# Sind die Wörter "laut" und "lauter" verwandt

Tags: etymology

Duden und Wiktionary geben Wurzeln an, die sich extrem ähnlich sehen. .

**Laut** kommt wohl von **hlut** und **lauter** von etwas wie **(h)luttar**. Ersteres ist laut ... der Quellen ein Partizip mit der Bedeutung **gehört**, während zweiteres die Bedeutung **rein, klar** trug. Allerdings sehen sich die Herknftswörter so ähnlich, dass ich mir gut vorstellen könnte, dass sie einen gemeinsamen Ursprung haben. 
Weiß einer da etwas genaues? Was für eine Wortform ist **(h)luttar**? Ist es abgeleitet? Wenn ja, wovon?
1000,1 Dank

Comment: "lauter" hat noch eine weiter Bedeutung, z.B. "Lauter kluge Leute...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nach dem [Etymologischen Wörterbuch des Deutschen (nach Pfeifer)](http://www.dwds.de) sind die beiden Wörter wohl nicht verwandt; zumindest dann nicht, wenn der genannte Ursprung aus den jeweiligen griechischen/lateinischen Wurzeln stimmt:

> - **laut:** *weithin hörbar* [...] griech. *klytós (κλυτός)* ‘berühmt’, lat. *inclutus* ‘berühmt’
> - **lauter** *rein, ungetrübt, aufrichtig* [...] griech. *klýzein (κλύζειν)* ‘spülen, reinigen’ [...] alat. *cluere* ‘reinigen, spülen’

Inwieweit nun die griechischen und lateinischen, ebenfalls *"ähnlich"* klingenden, Wurzeln miteinander verwandt sind, wäre eine schöne altphilologische Frage, die aber hier vielleicht zu weit führt.

Comment: Ich finde, die griech. bzw. lat. Wörter ähneln sich aber auch verdammt stark. Ich sehe eine Verwandtschaft zwischen den beiden Wörter.

Comment: Ja ich bin der gleichen Meinung wie Em1... ich würde echt wahnsinnig gerne wissen ob es einen gemeinsamen Kern gibt und wie der ist... der kleinste gemeinsame Nenner zwischen "spülen" und "berühmt". Ich könnte mir vorstellen, dass es wirklich etwas wie "klar, deutlich" ist, denn das würde zu beidem passen, aber das sind leider nur Spekulationen... auf jeden Fall danke an Takkat :)